# How to send sensitive data to docker container during run time

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-secrets

I am trying to containerise API automation repo to run it on ci/cd(gocd). Below is the `Dockerfile` content.

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /api-automation

COPY . /api-automation

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install .

COPY api_tests.conf /usr/.ops/config/api_tests.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["pytest" "-s" "-v" "--cache-clear" "--html=report.html"]
```

Below is the content of `api_tests.conf` configuration file.

```
[user]
username=<user_name>
apikey=<api_key>

[tokens]
token1=<token1>
```

`api_tests.conf` is the configuration file and it has sensitive data like API keys, tokens etc(Note: Configuration file is not encrypted). Currently I am copying this config from repo to following location `/usr/.ops/config/api_tests.conf` in container but i do not want to do this as there are security concerns. So how i can copy this `api_tests.conf` file when i run container from ci/cd machine(it means, from Dockerfile, i need to remove instruction `COPY api_tests.conf /usr/.ops/config/api_tests.conf`).

My second question is,
If I create a secret file using command `docker secret create my_secret file_path`,  how i can copy this secret `api_tests.conf` file when i run container.

Note: Once `api_tests.conf` file is copied to container then i need to run command "pytest -s -v --cache-clear --html=report.html"

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: I suggest you to use environment variables. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

Comment: one way is to pass environment variables as suggested, the second thing is mounting the file from host to container, and the third option is to pull from S3 or some cloud during boot time

Comment: @mchawre Thanks for suggestion.  I tried using --env-file(docker run -it --env-file /Users/basavarajlamani/Documents/api_tests.conf --name api-automation docker-image-api-automation) and i am able to get key=value into container but my configuration file has multiple sections and under each section key=value is there as i described in my initial question. How i can copy same file into container from host?

Comment: @BasavarajLamani If you just want to copy the .conf file then use volume mounting option `docker run -itd -v /Users/basavarajlamani/Documents/api_tests.conf:/path/to/api_test.conf image-name`. Let me know If I interpret your question properly.

Comment: @mchawre Thanks a lot for your help. It answered my first question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid putting this line `COPY api_tests.conf /usr/.ops/config/api_tests.conf` in `dockerfile` then use `-v` option of `docker run` command which mounts file/dir from host into container filesystem.

```
docker run -itd -v /Users/basavarajlamani/Documents/api_tests.conf:/usr/.ops/config/api_tests.conf image-name
```

If you want to use [docker secret](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets) to copy config file

- Make sure you're using `docker swarm`, since `docker secret` works with `swarm orchestrator`.
- Create docker secret with contents of config file `docker secret create api_test.conf /Users/basavarajlamani/Documents/api_tests.conf`
- `docker secret ls` will show the created secret.
- Run your docker container as a service in swarm.

```
docker service create \
     --name myservice \
     --secret source=api_test.conf,target=/usr/.ops/config/api_tests.conf \
     image-name
```

**NOTE:** You can also use [docker config](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/) rather than docker secret, the only difference is they are not encrypted at rest and are mounted directly into the container’s filesystem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have local image and i haven't uploaded to registry like docker hub but in future i will upload it to private registry. Currently I want to test locally, so after running container using `docker service create --name service-api-automation --secret source=api_tests.conf,target=/usr/.ops/config/ docker-my-image`, I am getting following error `image my-image:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record its digest. Each node will access my-image:latest independently, possibly leading to different nodes running different versions of the image.`